# What is the definition of the phrase"on in the balance"?

Tags: meaning

In a 1:38 minuts video of a George Harrison interview from minut 0:52 he says:

> "I think on in the balance......" and from that video that is the I get confused

[the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LTwIb0ELg8)"

does anybody know what that means, "on in the balance"???

Comment: Do you have a spell checker?  Please make use of it to catch mistakes like "minut".

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing here except a mis-speak and a hesitation.

> I think, [orrn...garbled]  in the balance, he would have...

George seems to stumble over what he is going to say.  He probably started to say "on balance" and then changed his mind and said "in the balance".

He ended up choosing the wrong expression.  "On balance" means "after considering both sides" and "in the balance" means "in an uncertain state". The context here strongly suggests that Harrison means "on balance".

Comment: I'm not "Sir James"!  You can only get that title from the Queen, and I haven't received a knighthood (yet).  I don't like being called "sir", which implies I'm better than you.

Comment: I'm sorry. I knew you could only get that title from the Queen i was just messing around here. :)